# Professional typesetting math font typeface

Tags: fonts, fontspec, math-fonts, typefaces

I wish to create some LaTeX documents for myself using a specific font. I have seen this font in many of the early 20th century papers. I found a good example at http://chalkdustmagazine.com/blog/is-there-a-perfect-maths-font/. I am talking about the font in the ***second*** example:

[image]

On the website, they mention that this is a Professional Typesetting Font from a 1945 UCL math exam.

Comment: Cambria math I think.

Comment: Cambria Math would be the 5th one. The 2nd one is the one I would like to know.

Comment: The 2. font not exist. It is an old character.

Comment: Number 2 seems very like the font used by the Soviet publisher Mir.

Comment: @egreg Do this font it exists? For my humble opinion the same font not exist. Please, can you see this link? http://chalkdustmagazine.com/blog/is-there-a-perfect-maths-font/ (Professional typesetting, from a 1954 UCL maths exam paper.).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments